# How to configure lasso regression to not penalize certain variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use lasso regression in python.
I'm currently using lasso function in scikit-learn library.

I want my model not to penalize certain variables while training. (penalize only the rest of variables)

Below is my current code for training

```
rg_mdt = linear_model.LassoCV(alphas=np.array(10**np.linspace(0, -4, 100)), fit_intercept=True, normalize=True, cv=10)
rg_mdt.fit(df_mdt_rgmt.loc[df_mdt_rgmt.CLUSTER_ID == k].drop(['RESPONSE', 'CLUSTER_ID'], axis=1), df_mdt_rgmt.loc[df_mdt_rgmt.CLUSTER_ID == k, 'RESPONSE'])
```

df_mdt_rgmt is the data mart and I'm trying to keep the coefficient for certain columns non-zero.

glmnet in R provides 'penalty factor' parameter that let me do this, but how can I do that in python scikit-learn?

Below is the code I have in R

```
get.Lassomodel <- function(TB.EXP, TB.RSP){
  VT.PEN <- rep(1, ncol(TB.EXP))
  VT.PEN[which(colnames(TB.EXP) == "DC_RATE")] <- 0
  VT.PEN[which(colnames(TB.EXP) == "FR_PRICE_PW_REP")] <- 0

  VT.GRID <- 10^seq(0, -4, length=100)

  REG.MOD <- cv.glmnet(as.matrix(TB.EXP), as.matrix(TB.RSP), alpha=1, 
  lambda=VT.GRID, penalty.factor=VT.PEN, nfolds=10, intercept=TRUE)

  return(REG.MOD)
}
```

Comment: An inelegant hack might be to scale and center all of your variables and then multiply all the variables you want to penalize by a large constant like 100 (and do not alter the variables that you do not want to be penalized). Since those coefficients will be much larger the regularization will "focus" on those variables

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you can't. Of course it's not an theoretical issue, but just a design-decision.

My reasoning is based on the available [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso) and while sometimes there are undocumented functions, this time i don't think there is what you need because the [user-guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#lasso) already posts this problem in the 1-factor-norm-of-all form `alpha*||w||_1`

Depending on your setting you might modify sklearn's code (a bit scared about CD-tunings) or even implement a customized-objective using scipy.optimize (although the latter might be a bit slower).

Here is some example showing the scipy.optimize approach. I simplified the problem by removing intercept's.

```
""" data """
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
A = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
alpha=0.1
weights=np.ones(A.shape[1])

""" sklearn """
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=alpha, fit_intercept=False)
clf.fit(A, y)

""" scipy """
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def lasso(x):  # following sklearn's definition from user-guide!
    return (1. / (2*A.shape[0])) * np.square(np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - y, 2)) + alpha * np.linalg.norm(weights*x, 1)

""" Test with weights = 1 """
x0 = np.zeros(A.shape[1])
res = minimize(lasso, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp': False})
print('Equal weights')
print(lasso(clf.coef_), clf.coef_[:5])
print(lasso(res.x), res.x[:5])

""" Test scipy-based with special weights """
weights[[0, 3, 5]] = 0.0
res = minimize(lasso, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp': False})
print('Specific weights')
print(lasso(res.x), res.x[:5])
```

Output:

```
Equal weights
12467.4614224 [-524.03922009  -75.41111354  820.0330707    40.08184085 -307.86020107]
12467.6514697 [-526.7102518   -67.42487561  825.70158417   40.04699607 -271.02909258]
Specific weights
12362.6078842 [ -6.12843589e+02  -1.51628334e+01   8.47561732e+02   9.54387812e+01
  -1.02957112e-05]
```